# Testing for multiple conditions dynamically?

Tags: javascript

Either my question is ludicrous or I'm searching the wrong thing because I can't find anything similar. I was wondering if I could create an if statement with multiple conditions dynamically? The only way that I can think of on the spot is something like this:

```
function someTest( numOne, numTwo ) {
for (var i = numOne; i < numTwo; i++) {
   if (someCol[i].test === false) {
    return false;
   }
}
}

someTest( 20, 35 );
```

This is only an example to show you what I mean, since it goes through multiple if statements and if any of them arent true than it returns false and 'short-circuits' like a normal if statement with && multiple && parameters && . But this kinda forces you to use tables and makes else statements more complicated to do. If anyone has any advice or a better way, please do tell. Thanks for any input

EDIT: It's a little complicated, but if you insist :-P. I have 6 rows, each has 4 columns. So 24 total 'cells' or 'boxes' whatever you want to call them. Each box you can plus or minus, however it's a little trickier than that. You need at least 4 'points' in the first row to access the second row, so to access the 4th row you would need at least 12 points altogether.

Adding points is easy, it's removing the points that gets complicated. Since you can't just add the first 3 columns up and if there are more than 12 points you can remove a point from the 4th column, in case there are points in the columns above the 4th one, since you still need to have a minimum of points for there to be points in the 6th column for example. Does this make sense? I will try to create a quick jsfiddle to show you a running example. Give me a few

EDIT2:
http://jsfiddle.net/zBcBd/3/

Still working on it, but as you can see, you can't add points to the second row unless there are at least 4 points in the first row, then you cant add points in the third row until there are at least a total of 8 points. This was the easy part, what I'm trying to accomplish is make the removal of points but it has to test for EVERYTHING. So for example if there are points in the 6th row then you cant remove any points from the 5th row unless there are over 21 points to still support the 6th row, make sense?

Comment: There is no "universal test". Each test should be specialized depending on domain and then generalized *within* the domain, if appropriate. Since there is no domain/problem specified here, it is hard to suggest appropriate solutions.

Comment: JavaScript is a very powerful language where you can do all kinds of things, so the answer is probably, "Yes!" But it's not entirely clear here what you want to do. Instead of talking about the code, could we talk a bit (pun intended) about the data? What data do you start with, and what do you want the result to be when your code is done? If you give specific examples it will help make it clear how to write the code to do that. In the code you posted, for example, I see a reference to `someCol`. What is `someCol`?

Comment: Editted to explain more, give me a few minutes while I try to put this in jsfiddle.

Comment: K hope I didn't complicated it too much, jsfiddle took longer then I thought it would

Comment: @HateNames You mean something like: http://jsfiddle.net/gzHSQ/

Comment: @Benjamin Hehe I love you for trying. You're awesome. It's not working perfectly though, this is why I said it gets complicated. First off you can't remove points from a row once it hits 4 points, even though as long as there aren't any points in the rows above you should be able to. And secondly if I put 5 points in the first row, 3 points in the second row and then 1 point in the third row, I shouldn't be able to remove a point from the first row since 4 + 3 = 7 so you shouldn't have access to the third row yet there will be 1 point in it. Make sense? I'm actively working on this too btw,thx

Comment: @HateNames Sorry, was AFK, I whipped up something with Knockout, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t9Qxc/

Comment: I can't thank you enough for all the work you put into this. It's still not 100% working but it's given me more then enough to work on since I should be doing this myself to begin with and I want to get this working myself anyway. So seriously, cant thank you enough for all your help and choosing your answer as best. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do clever syntax is having an array of functions returning boolean.

```
function biggerThanThree(){
    return x>3;
}
function smallerThanFive(){
    return x<5;
}

var predicates = [biggerThanThree,smallerThanFive];

//matches all conditions
var valid = predicates.reduce(function(x,y){return x&&y(); },true);
//matches any condition
var somevalid = predicates.reduce(function(x,y){return x||y(); },true);
```

#### [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayFCh/)

For your specific needs, you can do something even more clever and generate the functions you check dynamcially:

```
var rows = [["+","+","+","-","-","+"],["+","+","+","-","-","+"],["+","+","+","-","-","+"]];
// accepts a row number and asserts that enough elements are in so far
function soFarHasMore(upToRowNum){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<upToRowNum;i++){
        sum+=rows[i].filter(function(x){return x==="+"}).length;
    }
    console.log(sum);
    return sum>=4*upToRowNum;
}

var predicates = [];
// generate functions dynamically and fixate their value of `i`
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    predicates.push(soFarHasMore.bind(null,i+1));//pushes predicates dynamically    
}

var valid = predicates.reduce(function(x,y){return x&&y(); },true);//matches all conditions
```

#### [here is a working demo of that](http://jsfiddle.net/vEWJs/)

Note: I used reduce with || and && because I like reduce. However, I think there is a more semantic version available:

```
predicates.every(function(elem){ // Same as &&
    return elem();
};

predicates.some(function(elem){ // Same as ||
    return elem();
};
```

Comment: Note, reduce works on modern browsers only. It should be shimmed for older ones.

Comment: +1 thanks for taking the time to write all that up for me, unfortunately I guess I didn't give enough details to express exactly what I wanted so I edited, sorry to trouble you and thanks once again